# How to modify text in vim .zshrc?

Tags: macos, zsh

I follow the commmand vim .zshrc to open an text editor.

The first time I add my text, but now I can't modify or erase previous text. I can only add new without erase previous

Comment: Why do you use vim if you don't know how to use it?  Use textedit "open -a TextEdit.app .zshrc"

Comment: Just follow a reply to an issue, but found, for people who search, it need only to press "I"

Comment: `vimtutor` is a good starting point.

Comment: Asking how to use a particular text editor is not a programming question. Try vim.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Nitneuq : See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vim/index.htm). I was always puzzled that so many of my fellow programmers love `vim`, but this is the first time I have seen someone wanting to use vim without knowing how to do it....